# Just built a new computer. Power will not turn on – clicks once, then nothing

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

I bought a bunch of new parts and put it all together to test it all out, before putting it all into my case. I then assembled everything into my case, attempted to turn it on, and *nothing* happened but a single click from the PSU.

I've got a Corsair CS450M modular PSU, and my motherboard is a ASRock H97 Anniversary ATX LGA1150.

Even when I just have my power button, PSU and motherboard connected, hitting the power switch only generates that click and nothing else. I have another PSU, a 380W that came stock with an HP desktop some years ago that I had been using until now, and when I plug it into the motherboard and attempt to turn it on, nothing at all happens.

Is there some way I can test my Power Supplies to see if they have somehow gone bad, or if my Motherboard has gone kaput? I'm really not sure how to test this sort of thing out, and it was working just fine before I put it all into my case.

Comment: I'd double check all the connections. *Specifically* the one that supplies power to the CPU

Comment: Take all the parts out that aren't needed.  Leave CPU, onboard GPU, and memory.  If that boots, add stuff back until it doesn't.  The last thing connected was the problem.

Comment: Newer motherboards may have several connectors.  Make sure you have all of them on.  Also you MIGHT need to have the CPU in place with at least 1 stick of RAM.  It really depends on the manufacturer.  Also make sure the RAM is in the recommended 1st slot.  For my ASUS HERO the first slot was A2 that it said it should be in however I'm sure it can vary.

Comment: If I understand correctly it seemed to be working before putting it into the case. In that situation one possibility is that you just might have a faulty Power On Switch on the cabinet. Do a test run again, bare this time out of the case with just PSU, CPU with heat sink, 1 RAM and CPU power connector plugged in. Short the power pin on Mobo to turn it on and check.

Comment: Turns out; the wiring was actually reversed for the Power+ and Power- on the motherboard (or, they're mislabeled). I guess the first time I tested it, I accidentally plugged it in "backwards" and it worked. T'was a strange one, but everything seems to work fine, and they're the only plugs on the entire Mobo that are backwards/mislabeled.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out; the wiring was actually reversed for the Power+ and Power- on the motherboard (or, they're mislabeled). I guess the first time I tested it, I accidentally plugged it in "backwards" and it worked. T'was a strange one, but everything seems to work fine, and they're the only plugs on the entire Mobo that are backwards/mislabeled.

Comment: That's *odd* since thise are rarely polarised. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I think theres a power switch in the motherboard. Try switching that on then some lights should appear in the motherboard.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).